# How can i use normal resource inside of namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**My Controller**

```
account
-profiles_controller.rb
```

**My Views**

```
account
-profiles
 --index.html.haml
```

**My routes**

```
namespace :account do
  resources :profiles
end
```

currently working in the form of this url.
http://localhost:3000/account/profiles

but I want it to be this way.
http://localhost:3000/profiles

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scope` instead of `namespace`

```
scope module: "account" do
  resources :profiles
end
```

**OR**

You can also write it as

```
resources :profiles, module: "account"
```

See [*controller-namespaces-and-routing*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for more info